# Action Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to send form data to aspx.cs page view below codes.

But this error generated:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please guide me.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>



 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">

  <title></title>

  </head>

<body>

 <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="Default2.aspx">

<input id="Text1" type="text" value="dgfdh"  runat="server" name="Text1"/>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

---

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = Request.Form["Text1"].ToString();

}
```

Comment: Have your tried to list contents of the Request.Form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are running the page for the first time, there is no form yet (the aspx side is created *after* the cs part is run), and therefore `Request.Form` has no fields yet.

Since the values of the form will be sent only upon submit (for example when clicking on a "Submit" button), you should put your assignment in a condition that checks if we've gotten to the page upon submit:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack){
         TextBox1.Text = Request.Form["Text1"].ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: @Saba, glad to have helped :-). See also Jon Skeet's answer. He has helpful info there too.

Answer (score 1):

When you load the page for the first time, there won't be any form values yet, because none will have been sent from the client. So `Request.Form["Text1"]` will be null.

Perhaps you should check `Page.IsPostBack` first? Ideally you should always validate that you've got all the form values you expect before using them anyway, of course.

It's not clear why you're calling `ToString()` in the first place though - the expression `Request.Form["Text1"]` is *already* a string isn't it? Can't you just use:

```
TextBox1.Text = Request.Form["Text1"];
```

You should check what happens if you set the `Text` property to null though. You could always use the null coalescing operator to fix that:

```
TextBox1.Text = Request.Form["Text1"] ?? "";
```

Answer (score 1):

As your Design View i don't see any control with the ID `TextBox1` so please first create a control with the Following id and then go for

```
TextBox1.Text = Request.Form["Text1"].ToString();
```

you can also do this like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox TextBox1=new TextBox();

    TextBox1.Text = Request.Form["Text1"].ToString();

}
```

Comment: Although what you're saying looks true, that wasn't the OP's problem. You _could_ post this as a comment, however.